# "The api-version query parameter (?api-version=) is required for all requests" - PowerAutomate HTTP Get request failing with api-version defined

Tags: sharepoint-online, power-automate

I have set up an API endpoint in a PowerAutomate flow using the action named:

`Receive an HTTP Request`

I have set the Method on that action to `GET`.

I have copied the endpoint URI that is generated on Save.

I am trying to send a GET request to that endpoint in another PowerAutomate flow using the action named:

`HTTP`

And I have specified the Method there is a GET request.

When I run the GET request flow, I get the error:

> The api-version query parameter (?api-version=) is required for all requests.

This query parameter is definitely in the request.

See screenshot of the relevant part of the URI called and the error message below:

[image]

Why is it failing and what is the solution?

**UPDATE 01:**

I have found that the GET request works fine if there are no query parameters defined in the action.  As soon as I add the query parameters and try and run the flow, I get the error:

[image]

**UPDATE 02:**

For some unknown reason, it works if I append the query parameters to the URI directly, eg:

```
https://***.***.logic.azure.com:443/workflows/***/triggers/manual/paths/invoke?api-version=2016-06-01&sp=%2Ftriggers%2Fmanual%2Frun&sv=1.0&sig=***&param01=some%20value&param02=hello&param03=goodbye
```

It does not work if I use those `Queries` fields in the GUI.

Comment: Do you get the same error if you use URL just up to `invoke` like this: `https://***.***.logic.azure.com:443/workflows/***/triggers/manual/paths/invoke`?

Comment: Do you mean use the URI you suggested with the `Queries` defined in the GUI (not as parameters in the URI)?